# Парсинг инструментов разработчика (F12)

Tags: php, ajax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Кто знает, как реализовать следующую систему: человек указывает URL сайта, например, `https ://habrahabr. ru/post/173141/`, а скрипт сам, грубо говоря, нажимает F12, переходит в Network и парсит запросы? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не совсем уверен, но возможно вам поможет CodeCeption.

Comment: @АндрейБеспалов, тоже не уверен, мне нужно парсить, а не тестировать

Comment: Что значит парсит? Не совсем ясна задача. Нужно по ссылке на html скачать все прикрепленные css, js ... ?

Comment: @E_p, да, нужно парсить http-заголовки страницы. скорее всего, это реализуется через cURL...